# hierarchy viewer results interpretation

Tags: android, performance, hierarchy

Some days ago I've installed the updates for ADT Plugin in Eclipse and I've just tried the new **Hierarchy viewer** tool. Beside it took me a while to find that the measurements are calculated only at the first (parent) view, I have observed that the values shown are not the same every time, even if there are no changes in my application.

For example, I've launched in the emulator one of my applications, loaded it in the Hierarchy viewer and got the next results: (I've wanted to include the screen shots, but my reputation doesn't allow me to post pictures yet, so I'll just write the values)

**Measure:** 175.340 ms
**Layout:** 5.179 ms
**Draw:** 47.115 ms

Then, without any changes, I launched again the application, and got the following results:

**Measure:** 98.696 ms
**Layout:** 4.819 ms
**Draw:** 50.923 ms

Could someone tell me why there is such a big difference between the values of Measure, for example?

Also, did someone know the meaning / the difference between the 3 values provided: **Measure**, **Layout** and **Draw**? Are each related with some specific attributs of the views?

The Android developers page doesn't provide too many explanations for that, and all I know is those values must be as small as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at ["How Android Draws Views"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).
It has all the info of what the values Measure, Layout and Draw of a View are.

Comment: Thank you, for the link, indeed it explains quite well what happens when you draw a view; though, I am not sure yet about what can cause the differences in measurement, if I didn't change the project at all, just re-launched it; aren't the same methodes applied every time?

Comment: Ideally it should be same, but since android is a multi process and multi threaded system , it state is not same every time when you launch your application. Hence you observe different results.

Comment: Thank you, from the beginning I supposed this may be the case, though I was wondering what is the purpose of  Hierarchy Viewer showing these values, if they are different each time. But after some more tests, I see the results are somewhat in the same intervals.

Comment: The purpose of Hierarchy Viewer tool showing these values is to improve the performance of UI rendering.