# Measure, Layout, and Draw times in Hierarchyviewer

Tags: android

What is the difference between Measure, Layout, and Draw time in Android Hierarchyviewer tool? There is a nice article on Android Developers, however I can't find any information related on actual meanings of these three different time values... Can somebody explain me the difference? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [hierarchy viewer results interpretation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437796/hierarchy-viewer-results-interpretation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are basically 3 steps during the render process.  First, your view gets measured, this is the just the width and height.  Then the controls are go through layout, this basically just tells all the views where they are located inside the measurements.  And finally, everything is drawn.  This is where the controls are actually drawn on the canvas.  So those are probably the what you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Joe! This makes sense to me now.

Comment: For a bit more info, some of these steps can be skipped under certain circumstances. Measurement can be skipped if the MeasureSpec values are the same and the size would not change. Both measurement and layout usually do not need to happen when drawing. You should be concerned the most about your drawing time since it will happen much more frequently, and you should try to avoid unnecessary layouts when possible. Many operations on Views can `requestLayout()`, such as setting text, images, and other properties that alter size or position.